# Cannot add controller in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-controller

I'm trying to add a controller in my ASP.NET MVC project.

I am using Entity Framework Code First (5.0), and when I right-click the *Controllers* folder in my project and selecting *Add Controller*:

[image]

After selecting *MVC controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework* and other settings, I get this message:

> There was an error generating '{0}'. Try rebuilding your project.

[image]

### Update

Seems that the special constructor I added to the `DbContext` caused the problem. After commenting out the constructor, it's working back again, however this message appeared:

[image]

Anyway I checked the activity log and found no info regarding that issue or any record at the occurrence timeline, should you know what this is all about, please comment on.

Comment: Show me your scree to add Controller with Selection.

Comment: There you go, uploaded.

Comment: Try to Rebuild your project before Creating a controller.

Comment: Think I'd bother posting a question with screenshots before doing that?

Comment: You could try and scaffold one from package manager?

Comment: @MattSull87 sounds like a good idea, anyway, I got a workaround for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the special constructor I added to the `DbContext` caused the problem. After commenting out the constructor and re-compiling, it's working back again.

Perhaps I should wrap the constructor contents in a conditional statement that is skipped at design-time, meanwhile commenting-out is enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

"Build the application before going on to the next step. If  you don't build the application, you'll get an error adding a controller."
"If you get an error, you probably didn't build the application before starting adding the controller."
You must run project, probability.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller

Answer (score 0):

Just have an empty `DbContext` subclass when adding the controller. Then it will work fine for you...

Comment: But I will not be able to add the models used by the desired `DbContext`. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16037588/75500) answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows OS press 
**CTRL + SHIFT + B** to build the application then try again to add Controller