# Resolved: There was an error generating '..Context'. Try rebuilding your project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning Insert ,update, delete using Entity Framework in MVC from

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8f4P8U1a2TI

I add new Entity Framework 
and after that adding new Controller.

here is my Setting for adding new Controller

[image]

when I save adding Controller . Error Comes ..

> There was an error generating
>   'MvcApplication1.Models.EmployeeContext'. Try rebuilding your project.

EmployeeContext.cs

```
 public  class EmployeeContext :DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
```

(Employee class is in seperate Assembly)

Solutions i tried :

1. [Cannot add controller in ASP.NET MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035939/cannot-add-controller-in-asp-net-mvc-project)

it says some special constructor in dbcontext caused problem... i dont have any

2. uninstall and reinstall entity framework from nuget several times

3.Database.SetInitializer() placed in  Application_Start method in Global.asax.cs

whats Wrong ? please suggest ...

Answer (score 1):

OK , Resolved .. Here what i did

1. I removed  Model Class , Context Class and add , delete , save operations ..which were manually created . Entity Framework Auto Generates these things . so the conflict was occuring...
2. while adding New controller ..In DataContext Class Section ..Connectionstring name should be filled which is Auto Generated by Entity Framework . i was filling incorrect thing

Hope that might be helpful